# CNN model is overfitting to data after reaching 50% accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to identify 3 (classes) mental states based on EEG connectome data. The shape of the data is 99x1x34x34x50x130 (originally graph data, but now represented as a matrix), with respectably represent [subjects, channel, height, width, freq, time series]. For the sake of this study, can only input a 1x34x34 image of the connectome data. From previous studies, it was found that the alpha band (8-1 hz) had given the most information, thus the dataset was narrowed down to 99x1x34x34x4x130. The testing set accuracy on pervious machine learning techniques such as SVMs reached a testing accuracy of ~75%. Hence, by goal is to achieve a greater accuracy given the same data (1x34x34). Since my data is very limited 1-66 for training and 66-99 for testing (fixed ratios and have a 1/3 class distribution), I thought of splitting the data along the time series axis (6th axis) and then averaging the data to a shape of 1x34x34 (from ex. 1x34x34x4x10, 10 is the random sample of time series). This gave me ~1500 samples for training, and 33 for testing (testing is fixed, the class distributions are 1/3).

Model:

```
SimpleCNN(
  (conv1): Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
  (conv2): Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))    
  (pool1): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (drop1): Dropout(p=0.25, inplace=False)
  (fc1): Linear(in_features=9248, out_features=128, bias=True)
  (drop2): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
  (fc2): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=3, bias=True)
)
CrossEntropyLoss()
Adam (
Parameter Group 0
    amsgrad: False
    betas: (0.9, 0.999)
    eps: 1e-08
    lr: 5e-06
    weight_decay: 0.0001
)
```

Results:
The training set can achieve an accuracy of 100% with enough iteration, but at the cost of the testing set accuracy. After around 20-50 epochs of testing, the model starts to overfit to the training set and the test set accuracy starts to decrease (same with loss).

[image]

What I have tried:
I have tried tuning the hyperparameters: lr=.001-000001, weight decay=0.0001-0.00001. Training to 1000 epochs (useless bc overfitting in less than 100 epochs). I have also tried increasing/decreasing the model complexity with adding adding addition fc layers and varying amount of channels in CNN layers form 8-64. I have also tried adding more CNN layers and the model did a bit worse averaging around an accuracy of ~45% on the test set. I tried manually scheduling the learning rate every 10 epochs, the results were the same. Weight decay didn’t seem to effect the results much, changed it from 0.1-0.000001.

From previous testing, I have a model that achieves 60% acc on both the testing and the training set. However, when I try to retrain it, the acc instantly goes down to ~40 on both sets (training and testing), which makes no sense. I have tried altering the learning rate from 0.01 to 0.00000001, and also tried weight decay for this.

From training the model and the graphs, it seems like the model dosn’t know what it’s doing for the first 5-10 epochs and then starts to learn rapidly to around ~50%-60% acc on both sets. This is where the model starts to overfit, form there the model’s acc increases to 100% on the training set, and the acc for the testing set goes down to 33%, which is equivalent to guessing.

Any tips?

Edit:

The model’s outputs for the test set are very very close to each other.

```
0.33960407972335815, 0.311821848154068, 0.34857410192489624
```

The average standard deviation for the whole test set between predictions for each image are (softmax):

```
0.017695341517654846
```

However, the average std for the training set is `.22` so...

F1 Scores:

```
Micro Average: 0.6060606060606061
Macro Average: 0.5810185185185186
Weighted Average: 0.5810185185185186
Scores for each class: 0.6875 0.5 0.55555556
```

Here is a confusion matrix:
[image]

Comment: It seems that the model labels all samples to one class. Did you use this data augmentation for SVM test too?

Comment: No, the SVM training set consisted of 66 samples and the testing set was comprised of 33 samples

Comment: I think it might be the data augmentation. Could you give us the code and some sample in the question?

Comment: Could you include the F1-score and the AUC plot of the model as this is a multiclass classification problem these would be better measures to evaluate the models performance.

Comment: @mirzanahal, specifically what code?

Comment: @yuRa I added the F1 scores

Comment: How does the current SVM algorithm handle data preparation? Does it also average over the freq and time axes? It seems like you'd throw away a lot of information if you simply took the mean. Maybe looking at generating features like min, max, trend per freq band would help accuracy but still enable you to reduce the dimentionality. As an alternative you could look into using a recursive layer such as LSTM to encode the time dimension.

Comment: @quizzical_panini, yes the SVM averaged over the same freq and time axes. I would like to change the input shape and size, but since I am trying to compare SVM performance with DL models, I am trying to keep the input data the same. The data was first represented in graphs, then into a matrix representation. Do you know of any DL model that have been trained on matrix representations of graphs? I know graph-CNN exist but I am trying to stick with the same input for now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think the problem you're facing is that your dataset is on the small side after data prep for a "deep" model. I also don't think you're going to find any pretrained models that are remotely similar to this use case.

You could create your own pretrained model on a similar task e.g. create a model that predicts the next frame (34x34x4) then use transfer learning to build a classifier with the same weights.

Comment: That seems like a great idea, would I use a convolutional layer to extract the features and the use a transpose convolutional layer to decrease the dimensionality (channels) but increase size? Then from there use the convolutional layer (with the same weight) with dense layers? On a side note, the testing set was collected from different subjects at a different facility, this may be why the is having a tough time generalizing.

Comment: @AdityaKendre your profile says you are a "12th grader". Wow! Keep it up man!

Comment: @MichaelWarner, thanks!

Comment: @quizzical_panini, I created an auto encoder and striped the transpose layers from it and used the cnn layers (while frozen) with fc layers but this generated similar results. Anything else I can try?

Comment: I think I found what the problem is, since the testing set and the training set were recorded on different subjects and facilities, its extremely hard for the model to generalize. I switched the testing set and training set and the same results ensued. However, when I split the training set into a testing and training set, the model looked like it generalized to the testing set; but when tested on the original testing set it did not do well (~45% accuracy). I think I somehow need to do something to both datasets than just normalization and standardization.

Answer (score 3):

I have some suggestions, what I would try, maybe you've already done it:

- increase the probability of dropout, that could decrease overfitting,
- I did not see or I missed it but if you don't do it, shuffle all the samples,
- there is not so much data, did you thought about using other NN to generate more data of the classes which are having the least score? I am not sure if it is the case here but even randomly rotating, scaling the images can produce more training examples,
- another approach you can take, if you haven't done it already, use transfer learning using another popular CNN net and see how it is doing the job, then you can have some comparison, whether it is something wrong with your architecture or it's lack of examples :)
  I know these are just suggestions but maybe, if you haven't try some of them, they will bring you closer to the solution.
  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I tried increasing the probability of dropout, the loss/accuracy seemed to remain the same. I doubled checked I was shuffling the data. I think your talking about creating a GAN in the 3rd point, which I did, and the discriminator had the same metrics. For the last point, I originally tired transfer learning, however I quickly realized that those models are trained for object detection, so those pretrained weight don't really help here.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: No, in 3rd point I'm just talking about manually modifying images, using e.g. openCv or Pillow changing the orientation and size of the images to generate more data

Comment: Oh ok, so each pixel in the image represents a specific spot in the brain, changing the pixels position would mean that the activity in the brain is happening at a different place. Which wouldn't work. The only data augmentation technique I have used is spitting based on the time series, essentially taking the averages of different ranges in time. However, this didn't increase the accuracy very much.

Comment: Ah ok I see... well then that wouldn't work at all :(

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, do you have others you would like me to try?

Comment: Well it s hard, it seems clearly to be overfitting due to not enough data, I guess playing with drop out may be the case, creating deepr nn also may help to figure out some more things but then from antoher hand it can also lead to overfit, but ye maybe try to add more layers and try different configurations of hyperparams and dorp probability

Comment: I will try playing around with drop out more, and creating 4 layers deep cnns. Thanks for the help!